# DSolve and NDSolve plots are different

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve for a steady state Fick's second law equation with a simple reaction term.

However, when I compare both DSolve and NDSolve they both give very different plots. 
[image: DSolve Plot]
[image: NDSolve Plot]

Why is that? Is there something wrong with the way I am setting up my code?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

DiffCo = 1*10^-6; (*Diffusion coefficient*)
k = 0.25;

eqn = (DiffCo*(D[u[x], x, x]) + (k*u[x])) == 0

sol = DSolve[{eqn, DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 100}]

sol1 = DSolve[eqn, u, {x, 0, 100}]

Plot[u[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]

sol2 = NDSolve[{eqn, DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]}, u, {x, 0, 100}]

Plot[u[x] /. sol2, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Normaly diffusion coefficient is given in m^2/s. Are you sure, that you have to regard the first 100 m for x ?  You get something like `{{u -> Function[{x}, Cos[500 x] - Cot[50000] Sin[500 x]]}} ` . I think x should be measurd in mm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding is that when using `DirichletCondition`, NDSolve will automatically use FEM.  So it was using FEM already. The issue seems to be in the grid size used, by default in FEM. since you did not specify one, it used large one and that gave inaccurate result.

```
k = 1/4;
diffCo = 0.01;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};
eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + k*u[x] == 0;
solAnalytic = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x], {x, 0, 100}];
solNumeric = NDSolve[{eqn == 0, bc},u,{x, 0, 100},Method ->{"FiniteElement"}];

Plot[u[x] /. solNumeric, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The smaller the diffCo, the smaller the maxCellMeasure is needed. This manipulate shows this more clearly.  When `diffCo` is large, the default will work OK:

```
k = 1/4;
diffCo = 1;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};
eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + k*u[x] == 0;
solAnalytic = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x], {x, 0, 100}];
solNumeric = 
  NDSolve[{eqn == 0, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];
Plot[u[x] /. solNumeric, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which now matches the `DSolve` solution.

[image]

**Added**

btw, your ode is of form $\delta u''(x) + k u(x)=0$ where $\delta$ is very small. This calls for boundary layer theory and asymptotic expansion, which is used in these cases, and it gives good result as long as one is close to the point of expansion.

```
k = 1/4;
diffCo = 1/10^6;
bc = {u[0] == 1, u[100] == 0};
eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + k*u[x] == 0;
solAnalytic = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x], x];
Plot[Evaluate@solAnalytic, {x, 0, .05}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*use 50 terms in expansion around 0 *)
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, u[x], {x, 0, 50}];
Quiet[Plot[Evaluate@sol, {x, 0, .05}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 300]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Added Manipulate code**

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{k, u, x, bc, eqn, solAnalytic, solNumeric},
  k = 1/4;
  bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};
  eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + k*u[x] == 0;
  solAnalytic = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x], {x, 0, 100}];
  solNumeric = NDSolve[{eqn == 0, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> maxCellMeasure}];

  Grid[{
    {Plot[solAnalytic, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 300]},
    {Plot[Evaluate[u[x] /. solNumeric], {x, 0, 100}, 
      PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 300]}
    }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center]
  ]
 ,

 {{diffCo, 0.001, "diffCo"}, 0.001, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {{maxCellMeasure, 1, "MaxCellMeasure"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {diffCo, maxCellMeasure}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful!
Question, how did you place the two graphs on top of each other?

Comment: Also, how did you set up your Manipulate plot? When I try, I can't seem to get the graph to change. This is the code I'm using: `Manipulate[
 Plot[u[x] /. solAnalytic, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full], {diffCo, 
  1*10^-6, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {MaxCellMeasure, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: @J.Yang sorry, forgot to add Manipulate code. it is there now

Answer (score 9):

Using `FEM` will certainly give you the same solution as that of `DSolve`,

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{eqn, DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}]

Plot[u[x] /. sol2, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```